# In Visual Studio 2008, when I stop debugging an ASP Classic website Visual Studio always crashes

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, asp-classic

We are running Visual Studio 2008 (with the service pack) and are having troubles when we are debugging an [ASP Classic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) website.

The server is Windows 2003 SP2.  We are using Windows authentication.  We have a virtual directory that is an ASP.NET web application.

We can attach to the w3p process and debug just fine.  Breakpoints work, and we can view variable values.  The difficulty arises when it comes time to detach or stop the debugger.

Every time we take either approach (detach or stop the debugger) we get a series of crashes from Visual Studio.

I just separated the website into its own application pool and got the following error in the event log when I detached the debugger:

> .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3607 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A09795E) (80131506)

How can this problem be fixed?

Comment: says to doc - 'It hurts when i do *this*.' doc says.... 'Well stop doing *that* '.  ;-p  sorry could not resist. I feel your pain and I hope you get a real answer.

Comment: yeah, we've taken to other debugging techniques such as response.write or storing variables in session (and then creating a debug page that lists the content of the session)

Comment: I am of no help, but I definately have this problem too and it makes me cry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hot-fix. Check this Knowledge Base article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967631

Answer (score 0):

Nope not seeing this.  I do lot of debugging of Classic ASP with VS2008 without problems like this.  Apart from "Re-install stuff suggestion" I'm not sure what else you can do.

In the dim and distant past I've found debugging can be flakey when the process being debugged is running under reduced priviledged account but whether thats true now can't say.  You might try as an experiment setting all the identites for the processes involved to the same as your interactive logon but I don't hold out much hope that that will help.

What O/S are you running?

Comment: added some more details in the question above.

Comment: @yamspog: I also develop on Windows 2003, I don't get these problems.  You have the website run in its own pool or do you have other sites sharing the pool?  I've found its best to create a pool just for the application to be tested, give that pool an identity that matches the one used to logon interactively in which the IDE runs.

Comment: I put the website into its own app pool and started getting a new error in the event viewer: .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3607 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A09795E) (80131506).  Not a solution yet, but it provides a bit more insight.

Comment: @yamspog:  Sounds like you've your self a sickly machine there.